# How to configure authentication in spring security for different users from two different tables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

In my spring boot application, I have 2 different type of user - user and vendor which are stored in different tables in my SQL DB.

I have only allowed access to /user/login and /vendor/login which returns a JWT.

I am unable to understand how to configure spring security to check only the USERS table when someone requests /user/login and check only VENDORS table when vendor requests /vendor/login. Is this possible? If not could anyone suggest how do I configure spring security to authenticate users from different tables?

Here is my current configuration which only authenticates on USERS -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService myUserDetailsService;   // this fetches data from the USERS table

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    // *** How do I configure this to check both VENDORS OR USERS table? ***
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/auth/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/vendor/auth/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I have implementations of UserDetailsService for both user and vendor. Here is implementation for userService -

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public UserService() {
    }

    public UserService(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Users findOne(String id) {
        Optional<Users> user = repository.findById(id);
        return user.orElse(null);
    }

    public List<Users> findAll() {
        List<Users> users = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(users::add);
        return users;
    }

    public Users insert(Users user) throws UnknownError {
        // somecode here
    }

    public Users update(String id, Users user) {
       // some code here
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final Users user = findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user Found");
        }

        return new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

Here is the UserController (VendorController is similar to this) -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping(path = "/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest form) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(form.getEmail(), form.getPassword()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect Credentials");
        }

        final UserDetails user = service.loadUserByUsername(form.getEmail());
        Users returnedUser = service.insert(user);
        ResponseStructure response = new ResponseStructure(true, returnedUser);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the UserService look up both repositories

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private VendorRepository vendorRepository;

   // all the other stuff

    private Users findByUsername(String username){
        return userRepository.findByUserName(username);
    }

    private Vendors findByVendorName(String vendorName){
        return VendorRepository.findByVendorName(vendorName); // given you have such method declared in the Spring Data repository
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByName(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = findByUsername(name);
        if (user != null) {
             return new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
        }

        Vendors vendor = findByVendorName(name);

        if (vendor != null) {
             return new Vendor(vendor.getEmail(), vendor.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        else{
               throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user Found");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however this is not an ideal solution because we are going through the users table first and then the vendors table, and secondly if by any chance vendor or user have the same name and password, that might cause trouble.

Comment: Noticed that your request comes from different login urls. Maybe yo could add a userType to AuthenticationRequest  and select the right repository based on type of user.

Comment: The userType property you can add as a hidden input on your login form to make it simple
Or you can add HttpServletRequest as parameter to login method and get the use getRequestURI() to get to know where the request comes from